# Summing over lists in python - is there a better way?

Tags: python, list, sum

Is there a more sensible way of doing this? I want to make a new list by summing over the indices of a lot of other lists. I'm fairly new to programming and this seems like a very clunky method!

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,1,1,4,1]
list3 = [1,22,3,1,5]
list4 = [1,2,5,4,5]
...
list100 = [4,5,6,7,8]

i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    mynewlist[i] = list1[i]+list2[i]+list3[i]+list4[i]+...list100[i]
    i = i+1
```

Comment: First, don't create 100 variables named `list1`...; use a list of lists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a pretty good use case for [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = [1,1,1,4,1]
>>> list3 = [1,22,3,1,5]
>>> list4 = [1,2,5,4,5]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)]
[4, 27, 12, 13, 16]
```

or if you have your data as a list of lists instead of separate lists:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,4,1], [1,22,3,1,5], [1,2,5,4,5]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*data)]
[4, 27, 12, 13, 16]
```

similarly, if you store your data as a `dict` of lists, you can use [`dict.itervalues()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) or [`dict.values()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to retrieve the list values and use that in a similar fashion:

```
>>> data = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":[3,4,4]}
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*data.itervalues())]
[4, 6, 7]
```

---

Note that if your lists are of unequal length, `zip` will work up till the shortest list length. For example:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1], [1,22], [1,2,5]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*data)]
[4, 27]
```

If you wish to get a result that includes all data, you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (with an appropriate `fillvalue`). Example:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1], [1,22], [1,2,5]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in izip_longest(*data, fillvalue=0)]
[4, 27, 8, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of doing it like this. However, thinking about it some more I think what I need is a dictionary, not a list of lists---I need each list member to be easily user accessible. I'll try and work out how to do what I want as a dictionary.

Comment: @FakeDIY if you're using a `dict`, you can get the list of lists using [`.itervalues()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) or [`.values()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), e.g. `[sum(x) for x in zip(*dct.itervalues())]`

Answer (score 6):

While @Shawn's answer is correct, this is a case where I think `map` might be more elegant than list comprehensions:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = [1,1,1,4,1]
>>> list3 = [1,22,3,1,5]
>>> list4 = [1,2,5,4,5]
>>> map(sum, zip(list1, list2, list3, list4))
[4, 27, 12, 13, 16]
```

Comment: I agree. Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the first place is this: you should *never* have 100 variables in your code.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,1,1,4,1]
list3 = [1,22,3,1,5]
list4 = [1,2,5,4,5]
...
list100 = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

Instead, you should have something like

```
list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append([1,2,3,4,5])
list_of_lists.append([1,1,1,4,1])
list_of_lists.append([1,22,3,1,5])
list_of_lists.append([1,2,5,4,5])
...
```

Then you'd calculate the desired result like this:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```

Comment: However, if your lists aren't all the same length, zip will slice them to the smallest list's length (ignoring the tails). So, since zip essentially turns this set into a matrix, if your set is large enough, you may be better off using a numpy matrix.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed that all lists are the same size, but it is important to emphasize that the code relies on this assumption, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I also need to be able to access each list individually and in a user friendly manner. I think I need a dictionary, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read a python tutorial.

1. `sum(list1)` will give you the sum of that list.
2. You need to learn about `for` loops
3. Your lists should themselves be stored in a list
4. The way to rotate a collection of lists is to use `zip`:

   ```
   list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
   list2 = [1,1,1,4,1]
   list3 = [1,22,3,1,5]
   zip(list1,list2,list3)
   # matches up element n of each list with element n of the other lists
   #=> [(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 22), (3, 1, 3), (4, 4, 1), (5, 1, 5)]
   # now you want to add up each of those tuples:
   [sum(t) for t in zip(list1,list2,list3)]
   #=> [3, 25, 7, 9, 11]
   ```

To work a list of lists like this with `zip`, look at the `itertools` module, or learn about the `*args` syntax.